# Zxing me inhabilita botones despues de escanear codigo

Tags: zxing

Buen día,soy novato en programación android y espero puedan ayudarme.

Estoy realizando una aplicación para leer codigo QR y que puedan agregar datos de fecha y hora junto con un spinner, pero al leer el código no me permite seleccionar en el spinner ni ejecutar los botones.

```
    package com.example.hypno.scan;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import com.google.zxing.Result;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText scantxt,fecha,txthora;
    Button btscan,btnfecha,btnhora;
    private ZXingScannerView vistaescaner;
    int Permiso_Camara,Mes,Dia,Ano,hora,minuto,segundo;
    Spinner opciones;
    TextView mensaje1,mensaje2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fecha=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fecha);
        txthora=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.hora);
        btnfecha=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnfecha);
        btnhora=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnhora);
        mensaje1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.msj1);
        mensaje2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.msj2);
        scantxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtscan);


        btnfecha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Calendar cx= Calendar.getInstance();
                Dia=cx.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                Mes=cx.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                Ano=cx.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                DatePickerDialog dd= new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        fecha.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+year);

                    }
                },Ano,Mes,Dia);
                dd.show();
            }
        });

        btnhora.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Calendar cx=Calendar.getInstance();
                hora=cx.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                minuto=cx.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                segundo=cx.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                TimePickerDialog dd = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        txthora.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);

                    }
                },hora,minuto,true);
                dd.show();
            }
        });

        opciones = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp01);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.opciones, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        opciones.setAdapter(adapter);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new
                String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                Permiso_Camara

                );

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);
        } else {
            locationStart();
        }
    }

    public void Escanear(View view){
        vistaescaner = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        vistaescaner.setResultHandler(new zxingscanner());
        setContentView(vistaescaner);
        vistaescaner.startCamera();
    }

    class zxingscanner implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{

        @Override
        public void handleResult(Result result) {
            String dato = result.getText();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            vistaescaner.stopCamera();
            scantxt.setText(dato);
        }
    }

    private void locationStart() {
        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Localizacion Local = new Localizacion();
        Local.setMainActivity(this);
        final boolean gpsEnabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!gpsEnabled) {
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(settingsIntent);
        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);
            return;
        }
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) Local);
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) Local);
        mensaje1.setText("Localización agregada");
        mensaje2.setText("");
    }
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 1000) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationStart();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    public void setLocation(Location loc) {
        //Obtener la direccion de la calle a partir de la latitud y la longitud
        if (loc.getLatitude() != 0.0 && loc.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                    mensaje2.setText("Mi direccion es: \n"
                            + DirCalle.getAddressLine(0));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    /* Aqui empieza la Clase Localizacion */
    public class Localizacion implements LocationListener {
        MainActivity mainActivity;
        public MainActivity getMainActivity() {
            return mainActivity;
        }
        public void setMainActivity(MainActivity mainActivity) {
            this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        }
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            // Este metodo se ejecuta cada vez que el GPS recibe nuevas coordenadas
            // debido a la deteccion de un cambio de ubicacion
            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();
            String Text = "Mi ubicacion actual es: " + "\n Lat = "
                    + loc.getLatitude() + "\n Long = " + loc.getLongitude();
            mensaje1.setText(Text);
            this.mainActivity.setLocation(loc);
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // Este metodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS es desactivado
            mensaje1.setText("GPS Desactivado");
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // Este metodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS es activado
            mensaje1.setText("GPS Activado");
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            switch (status) {
                case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                    Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.AVAILABLE");
                    break;
                case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                    Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE");
                    break;
                case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                    Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }



}
```